# Confluent Kafka: How is serialization and partitioning specified in confluent-kafka-python client?

Tags: python, serialization, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

1) In Java Client, using producer.put() we can add serializers for Integers and Strings. How do we do this for confluent-kafka-python client?
2) How do we serialize protoBuf records?

Answer (score 0):

In recent version i guess it gives No such configuration property: "value.serializer" thus we will need to user SerializingProducer and value.serializer value should be callback

```
from confluent_kafka import SerializingProducer
import json


def json_serializer(msg, s_obj):
    return json.dumps(msg).encode('utf-8')


conf = {'bootstrap.servers': 'localhost:29092',
        'value.serializer': json_serializer}

producer_client = SerializingProducer(conf)


def producer_json_msg(topic_name, **args):
    producer_client.produce(topic_name, **args)

producer_json_msg('test_two', value={'test': "this is fine"})
producer_client.flush()
```

Answer (score -1):

For question #1: Add `key.serializer` and `value.serializer` in the config, as show below:

```
from confluent_kafka import Producer
import socket
conf = {'bootstrap.servers': "host1:9092,host2:9092",
    'client.id': socket.gethostname(),
    'key.serializer': 'key serializer classpath',
    'value.serializer': 'value serializer classpath',
    'default.topic.config': {'acks': 'all'}}
producer = Producer(conf)
```

For question #2: Implement your own ProtobufSerializer class and set {key|value}.serializer to it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you please let me know what are the available serialzers?

Comment: Check https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html for all known implementing subclasses of serdes.